# Pug mixins from external file not working

Tags: laravel, pug

I am working with Pug and I wanted to create some mixins to make some reusable components across whole project. I wanted to create some files just to make mixins separated and categorised. The problem occurs when I want to include file with mixins into my main file. For example:

```
body
    block content
        include ./components/mixins/_mixins.pug
        +user_avatar('', '#', 'Daniel')
```

This does not work (when I want to include mixins from separate file). I got this error: `jade_mixins.user_avatar is not a function`

But when I include mixin in the file it works:

```
body
    block content
        mixin user_avatar(avatar_url, profile_url, name)
            .user(class='4u 6u(small) 12u(xsmall)')
                a(href=profile_url)
                    .user-avatar-thumbnail.is-active(style="background-image: url('" + avatar_url + "')")
                    if name
                        span.user-name=name
        +user_avatar('', '#', 'Daniel')
```

Any clue what to do to fix it? And yeah, the path is correct. To compile pug I use the `laravel-elixir-jade` package for laravel's elixir.

Comment: Not sure whether this is the cause, but have you tried using the [`laravel-elixir-pug`](https://github.com/mrkmg/laravel-elixir-pug) package? Jade has been renamed to Pug, and maybe there are some changes in the newer package that fix this...

Comment: Actually I tried. I used `laravel-elixir-pug` package with exactly same configuration (valid with description of package) and it did not compile any  of my pug code. Gulp task run without any errors but the files weren't updated. Just like it couldn't find my files.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue on a clean setup, see my answer below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue, but on my machine, it seems to work just fine. I'm listing the setup I made for this below, maybe you can find the point where yours deviates from this one.

My directory structure:

```
|- html/
|--- template.html (generated after running gulp)
|- node_modules/
|- views/
|--- mixins/
|----- util.pug
|--- template.pug
|- gulpfile.js
|- package.json
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "gulpfile.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-15",
        "laravel-elixir-pug": "^1.3.2",
        "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6"
    }
}
```

My `template.pug`:

```
body
    block content
        include mixins/util
        +test()
```

The `util.pug` file:

```
mixin test()
    p Test
```

And the `gulpfile.js`:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-pug');

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix
        .pug({
            blade: false,
            src: './views',
            search: '**/*.pug',
            pugExtension: '.pug',
            dest: './html'
        });
});
```

After running `gulp` in the root directory, this produces the following `template.html`, as expected:

```
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Your code is correct. I managed to make it working. Changing package to pug did the trick. The reason why it didn't work for me was the code which got outdated while I changed package to pug and when running a gulp task I didn't see any errors, I saw them when I made a watcher, then the task stopped on an error. Now it runs perfectly.

Comment: Ah ok, glad to hear it helped!